# Extra loop iteration happening when looping through array of objects

Tags: php

I made this object array

```
$trailheads[] = new StdClass;
```

Then I was putting an object in there each time it looped

```
$trailheads[] = $trailhead;
```

Then I returned the whole thing from the function like this:

```
$ret->ok = empty($errors);
$ret->errors = $errors;
$ret->o = $trailheads;

return $ret;
```

Once I got the values back, and loop through the results in the trailheads[] I keep looping 3 times instead of the expected 2.  Is there a reason an extra iteration might be happening?

Here is how I try to loop:

```
foreach ($trailhead_list->o as $key)
{
    $objkey  = (object) $key;
    echo '<p><h3>Trailhead Name: '.$objkey->trailhead_name.'</h3></p>';
    }
```

Comment: I think you also need to show how you create the trailheads[] entries from what data; and what output you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this:

```
$trailheads[] = new StdClass;
```

your `$trailheads` array contains on element, an instance of StdClass.

Then you add more elements, but there will be that first one.

Maybe you wanted to initialize the `$trailheads[]` like that, but instead you gave value to one of the array elements. Use this instead:

```
$trailheads = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

> I made this object array
>
> $trailheads[] = new StdClass;

... appears to be the source of the extra array element.  Instantiate an array empty like this:

```
$trailheads = array();
```

Then loop and add objects:

```
$trailheads[] = $trailhead;
```

Also a note:  I am guessing you don't have notices or warnings enabled.  Turn them on while you develop.  The line `$trailheads[] = new StdClass;` would have generated a notice, since you are adding a new element to a variable that hasn't been declared as an array (or anything else).  PHP's loose typing is very forgiving, but this line would have generated a notice.

Warnings and notices on while you develop, turn them off for production.  It will help you avoid common bugs and it will make you a better programmer to boot.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
$trailheads[] = new StdClass;
```

You are assigning a new StdClass object into the $trailheads array.  That is to say you aren't declaring it as a variable but actually adding an element.